# IE not rendering UTF-8, but Unicode not working well

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, unicode, utf-8

I am quite a beginner. I am coding only with HTML and CSS and would like to stick to that for a while. Everything else is still too difficult for me. 
Well, accidentally I saved my notepad as Unicode and had UTF-8 for my charset. It seemed to work well. Even IE 11 had no problem on my modern laptop.

Some days ago, I opened my site on a public library (with Windows Server 2008 R2 and IE 11 as the only browser) and the computer would just show my code and not render the page.

Then I saved my notepad as UTF-8 as well. Now the public library is rendering the page but with some wrong characters. And even on my laptop IE 11 is showing wrong characters now, which was not the case before.

Interestingly, when I go to another page on the library and then press to go backward one page, then my page is rendered correctly. But if reload the page, the problem appears again.

What am I doing wrong? Should I use Unicode everywhere instead? Thank you for your kindness and your patience with a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a good choice. If your browser isn't reading the page as UTF-8, maybe it would help to put this tag in the head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I have this code already. If I open the notepad file from my file explorer with IE all is perfect. But if I open from my webpage online, IE distorts some signs. e.g.: " is rendered as â€œ or â€, and it won't show things like ã, õ correctly. I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: `â€œ` is what happens when the UTF-8 form of `“` is interpreted as Latin-1 instead of UTF-8.  Which means your HTML is properly encoded in UTF-8 but the web browser is NOT being told that the HTML is encoded in UTF-8. So either you are missing the `<meta charset="utf=8" />` tag (which BTW is for HTML5 only, for HTML4 use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` instead), or the web server is sending an HTTP `Content-Type` header with the wrong `charset` specified, overriding whatever the HTML says.

Comment: Alternatively, use HTML entities instead of actual characters.  Like `&quot;` (`"`), `&ldquo;` (`“`), `&rdquo;` (`”`), etc, then there is no ambiguity over what you want displayed regardless of charset.